# Big O list complexity 8 bytes vs 16 bytes

Tags: list, sorting, vector, big-o, deque

In the following link:

http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2012/12/cpp-benchmark-vector-list-deque/

If you scroll down to the section where he is comparing the sorts he first shows the results with an 8 byte data type, comparing list, vector and deque. For 8 bytes (and 128 bytes) data type the list is much slower than the vector and deque. However, at the bottom of the sort comparison he uses a 16 byte data type and suddenly the list is faster.

How can the list be slower for 8 and 128 bytes, but faster for a value in between (i.e. 16 bytes)??

EDIT: I noticed the same pattern in the random_insert section. List is slower than vector and deque for 8 byte and 32 byte data types, but MUCH faster for 16 byte?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the 16 byte data type is not a "trivial 16 byte data type", it states that:

> The non-trivial data type is made of two longs and has very stupid
>   assignment operator and copy constructor that just does some maths
>   (totally meaningless but costly). One may argue that is not a common
>   copy constructor neither a common assignment operator and one will be
>   right, however, the important point here is that it is costly
>   operators which is enough for this benchmark.

So this has nothing to do with 16 bytes being a magic number that makes list go slow, but its about the operator overloading on the non-trivial type that makes it go slow.

Comment: Sorry got so engrossed in everything I completely overlooked that (which I had read)